# MySQL Query SUM Total Based on Column Value

Tags: mysql

I have tables like below, with columns as following

```
Order      D.O   Cost   Maintenance    Total
ORD-0005    1    100       50           150
ORD-0005    2    50        120          170
ORD-0006    3    200       100          300
ORD-0006    4    150       50           200
```

Now I want to have total SUM based on Column 'ORDER'
So the result will look like this

```
Order      D.O   Cost   Maintenance    Total
ORD-0005    1    100       50           320
ORD-0005    2    50        120          320
ORD-0006    3    200       100          500
ORD-0006    4    150       50           500
```

The total value is sum from all cost+maintenance refer to Order Column
So the total in end right of columns was totaled from both records if they have same order id

Thank you..really appreciated it
Anyone can help me really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a sub-query that calculates the `SUM` and then join this to the output:

```
SELECT  a.`Order`,
        a.`D.O`,
        a.`Cost`,
        a.`Maintenance`,
        b.`Total`
  FROM  `myTable` a
    INNER JOIN (
               SELECT  `Order`,
                       SUM(`Total`) AS `Total`
                 FROM  `myTable`
                 GROUP BY `Order`
               ) b ON a.`Order` = b.`Order`
  ORDER BY a.`Order`
```

This will calculate the total value for each order in the sub-query, and then include that total value in the output for each `Order`.

Output:

| Order | D.O | Cost | Maintenance | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ORD-0005 | 1 | 100 | 50 | 320 |
| ORD-0005 | 2 | 50 | 120 | 320 |
| ORD-0006 | 3 | 200 | 100 | 500 |
| ORD-0006 | 4 | 150 | 50 | 500 |

Seen here in this [working fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6Yq7Z1NuhUzbWh8cwZvNQx/0).

Comment: i don't know whether i can use bad word in here, but.. damn..you are good..